# Access Denied while globbing file pattern in transfer data from Google Cloud Platform to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm quite new to the BigQuery world so apologize if I'm asking a stupid question.
I'm trying to create a scheduled transfer data job that import data into BigQuery from Google Cloud Storage.

Unfortunately I always get the following error message:

> ```
> Failed to start job for table MyTable with error PERMISSION_DENIED: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern.
> ```

I verified to have all the required permissions already but it still isn't working.

Comment: Can you tell me how are you creating this Data Transfer Job ? Also, does the user have the appropriate permissions to do so, such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/enable-transfer-service#granting_bigqueryadmin_access)?

Comment: Maybe this answer solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/64280733/1821558