# Query table in Google BigQuery has error "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern."

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new with Google BigQuery. Please forgive me if my question is a little simple.

Let me clarify the background of the issue:

1. Account1 create a bucket (Multi-region) and external table.

   [image]
2. Account1 can query the external table data successfully.

   [image]
3. Grant Account2 below roles on the project.

   [image]
4. Account2 log in BigQuery can see the table, but can't query data, with below error.

   [image]

I have done some research and enable BigQuery API, issue still occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are reading data from a bucket, you should also give the second user access to read the data from the given bucket.
Click on the bucket and from the menu select "Edit bucket permissions", then click "Add member" and grant the second user the "Storage object viewer" role. Alternatively you can use the IAM and grant this role across the whole project and thus granting read access to all buckets.

Comment: Thank you Hristofor your quick reply. After grant second user permission on bucket, the issue is resolved. Thanks again. :)

Comment: One more question, when I try to connect to this table in Power BI desktop via second user account, no table displays, may I know if I need grant any other permissions? Or how to resolve this? Thanks